# Последовательность функций. Swift

Tags: многопоточность, swift, анимация, очередь, uikit

*Доброго времени суток. 
В приложении при нажатии кнопки происходит анимация и показывается текст на экране. 
Нужно чтобы после нажатия на кнопку пошла анимация и если анимация не закончилась, то функция, где показывается текст или любая другая в классе, не должна работать.
Если коротко, то нужно  поставить в ожидание остальные функции пока одна не закончит свою роботу.

Пока есть это:

```swift
let operationQuene = OperationQueue()

@IBAction func startButtnAtion(_ sender: UIButton) {
    queneForFunc()
}

override  func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        queneForFunc()
    }
}

func queneForFunc()
{
    let blockOperationOne = BlockOperation{
        self.animateImage()
    }
    let blockOperationTwo = BlockOperation{
        self.answer()
    }
    operationQuene.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    blockOperationTwo.addDependency(blockOperationOne)
    operationQuene.addOperation(blockOperationOne)
    operationQuene.addOperation(blockOperationTwo)

}

func animateImage()
{
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi * 4
    rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0
    backGroundImage.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
}

func answer()
{

    //Show Text from array in UILabel

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Теория

Параметр [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform), который вы используете для поворота, поддерживает неявную (**implicit**) анимацию. Поэтому можно использовать метод [`UIView.animate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate) для анимирования поворота.

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
    self?.backGroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi * 4)
}, completion: { [weak self] _ in
    self?.answer()
})
```

*Заметка: тут используется `weak`, чтобdeiы view controller мог безопасно удалиться даже во время выполнения анимации*

### Решение

Ваш код можно переписать без использования очередей:

```swift
func queneForFunc() {
    animateImage { [weak self] in
        self?.answer()
    }
}

func animateImage(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    backGroundImage.transform = .identity
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.backGroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi * 4)
    }, completion: { _ in
        completion()
    })
}

func answer() {
    // Show Text from the array in UILabel
}
```

### Другой способ

Если же в качестве анимации будет использоваться что-то без поддержки неявных анимаций, то можно воспользоваться [`CATransaction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransaction):

```swift
func animateImage() {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi * 4
    backGroundImage.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [weak self] in
        self?.answer()
    }
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

В этом случае так-же можно убрать очереди.

Отмечу, что в основном в подобных случаях используется более высокоуровневый метод `animate` из первого варианта.

Answer (score 0):

Реализация , если кому то понадобится !

```
var isAnimating: Bool = false //1
    func animateImage(){
        guard !isAnimating else { //2
            return
        }
        isAnimating = true //3
        CATransaction.begin()
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:
            "transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi * 4
        rotationAnimation.duration = 2.0
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            self.answeForQuest()
        }
        backGroundImage.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
        CATransaction.commit()

    }
func answeForQuest()
{
//some code
}
```